# Reduce wifi scan delays in android

Tags: android, wifimanager, data-collection

I am trying to collect the RSSI data from WiFi access points in Android. However there is an issue related to model of the devices. Each device collects the data with different period varying from 1 to 6 seconds. My questions is that whether I can adjust a constant  collection period maybe to 3 or 4 data collection per second, regardless of device model. In previous APIs there was "start active scan" but now there is "start scan" function which collects data in passive mode. I would be very grateful if you have an idea which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Active Scan is not possible and so is removed from the later API levels.

It is an OS version or device dependent setting.
It takes roughly one second on android pixel,whereas on the G1 it takes significantly longer.

So,You cannot adjust the constant collection period because it is an OS version and/or device dependent setting.